# ASP.NET WebApi Action Return Types

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What should my actions be returning?

1. Typed Objects/Collections: `Customer` or `IEnumerable<Order>`
2. `HttpResponseMessage`
3. `IHttpActionResult`

And what is the best way to return one of the later two? Should I use `Ok` or `Content` helper methods?

Answer (score 2):

All action results will be converted to HttpResponseMessage by the framework, so the outcome of the three listed actions will be the same. However, the last one is the preferred way to return results to clients because it is more succinct. Let's have a look at three options in action.

Let's say there is a product repository like this one:

```
public interface IProductRepository
    {
        Product FindProductById(int productId);
    }

    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        private int _nextId = 1;

        public ProductRepository()
        {
            Add(new Product { Name = "Tomato soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1.39M });
            Add(new Product { Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M });
            Add(new Product { Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M });
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public Product FindProductById(int id)
        {
            return products.Find(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public Product Add(Product item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            item.Id = _nextId++;
            products.Add(item);
            return item;
        }

    }
```

And the product controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        private IProductRepository _repository;

        public ProductsController()
        {
            _repository = new ProductRepository();
        }

  }
```

Now, add a get action which returns objects as results.

```
        [Route("products/{productId}")]
        public Product GetReturnsObjects(int productId)
        {
            Product product = _repository.FindProductById(productId);

            if(product ==null)   //Throwing the exception skips the entire Http Response pipeline
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            return product;
        }
```

As you can see, in order to return anything but a Product, we have to throw an exception with an appropriate HttpStatusCode. Doing this will skip the response pipeline, unless there is an exception filter in the HttpConfiguration.

Next, let's create GET methods which returns HttpResponseMessage or IHttpActionResult

```
        [Route("messageproducts/{productId}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetReturnResponseMessage(int productId)
        {
             Product product = _repository.FindProductById(productId);

            if(product ==null)
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, product);
        }

         [Route("actionresultproducts/{productId}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetReturnsActionResult(int productId)
        {
              Product product = _repository.FindProductById(productId);

            if (product == null)
                return NotFound();


            return Ok(product);   //Same as Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, product);
        }
```

Apparently, the later is shorter and more succinct.

As regards the Ok() or Content(), you should use Ok() for the same reason.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Stumbled upon this because I had the same question. +1 for the examples. Do you happen to know the reason why Microsoft (again) provided multiple approaches? According to your explanation, such a thing as 'return Product' shouldn't exist in the first place, but it seems to be Microsoft's preferred way in their examples. Oh, and I like IHttpActionResult, things like 'return NotFound()' nicely draws from the *ubiquitous langague* of most products.

Comment: @Acrotygma I guess that they just wanted to make an API method look like normal .Net methods, so that was the reason why "return Object" was designed. In addition, the examples you looked at might be from the version 1 of the API, which didn't have IHttpActionResult.